# Do a task on an object after flush

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my project I want pusblish on RabbitMq the id of my object after flush, how can I do it ? Because, it appear in postPersist, the object is not already flushed, and in postFlush, I can't get the object ID.

```
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $object = $args->getObject();
    if (!$object instanceof Blast) {
        return;
    }

    $token = $this->tokenGenerator->generateToken();
    $object->setName($token);
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $object = $args->getObject();
    if (!$object instanceof Blast) {
        return;
    }

    // Publish in Messaging Queue
    $this->producer->publish($object->getId());

    // Set at last Blast in User session
    $this->session->set('last_blast', $object->getId());
}
```

Someone have an idea ? I've choose to do it in a subescriber, else, I add the postPersist part directly in the controller after the flush ?

Comment: as I can see there is no way to get entity's id in any doctrine event, but you can do it right in the controller after the flush

Comment: We have the entity id in postPersist, but the object is not yet in database. I go put the code in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

To perform an action after Doctrine finishes flush you need to hook onto `postFlush` event. It's fired once at the end of flush process thus does not contain any associated entity. To work this around you can schedule a RabbitMQ message, instead of publishing it right away, with `postPersist` and later "flush" the RabbitMQ messages queue. In code it'd be something like this:

```
class MessagePublisher
{
    private $scheduled = [];

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $object = $args->getObject();
        if (!$object instanceof Blast) {
             return;
        }

        $this->scheduled[] = $object->getId();
    }

    public function postFlush()
    {
        foreach ($this->scheduled as $id) {
             $this->producer->publish($id);
        }
        $this->scheduled = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :-) But the class is called one time, or for each subscribed events ? I've not try to do it, because I've thinked the class would be called 2 times, then on postFlush, the $scheduled will be empty.

Comment: @mpiot the class (and its data) will live throughout entire request (i.e. it's constructed once in the container), Doctrine is just calling methods you tell it to call.